# Beamer: How to stop adding outline page every other frame

Tags: beamer

The following are the codes I used. The problem is that the outline page will automatically append every other page, but actually, I only want to have the one outline frame at the beginning. How to stop automatically appending the outline pages?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
 \usepackage{tabularx} 

 \usetheme{Madrid}

\title{An empirical Bayes approach to predict
radiation-induced toxicity using large-scale
SNPs}



\author[C.e]{Ch   \\ \vspace{5mm}
Promotor: Prof. Olivier Thas  \\ Tutor: Chamberlain Mbah}

\institute[University]{\textbf {  University}}
\date{11 September 2017}



\subject{Theoretical Computer Science}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

% Let's get started
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage 
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{The general problem}

\begin{frame}{The general problem} %{Optional Subtitle}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item {
    Radiation-induced toxicities.
  }
  \item {
   Large-scale SNPs.
  }

  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Thesis objective}

% You can reveal the parts of a slide one at a time
% with the \pause command:
\begin{frame}{Thesis objective}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item {
    developing a prediction model for predicting radiation-induced normal tissue toxicities based on a large scale of SNPs.

    % \pause % The slide will pause after showing the first item
  }
  \item {   
   With this model, a subset of most influential SNPs will be selected. A clinician can examine only a subset of SNPs from an individual patient after being treated with radiotherapy to predict the risk of developing toxicity for this patient.
  }

  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
% ============dataset================================ 
 \subsection{The dataset}

\begin{frame}{The dataset }%{Optional Subtitle}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item {
    The endpoints.
  }
  \item {
   Large-scale SNPs.
  }

  \end{itemize}

\label{tab2}
\hfill \break
\end{frame}
% \section{Data description}

% % \subsection{Another Subsection}

\section{Data and methods}
\subsection{The dataset}
\subsection{Modelling}
\subsection{Estimation of the effect size $\beta_i$}
\subsection{SNPs selection}
\subsection{Evaluation of prediction performance}

\section{Simulation study}
\subsection{Simulation scenarios}
% \subsection{Data generation}
\subsection{Simulation results}
 \section{Real data application}

\section{Discussion and conclusion}


\begin{frame}{Blocks}
\begin{block}{Block Title}
You can also highlight sections of your presentation in a block, with it's own title
\end{block}
\begin{theorem}
There are separate environments for theorems, examples, definitions and proofs.
\end{theorem}
\begin{example}
Here is an example of an example block.
\end{example}
\end{frame}

% Placing a * after \section means it will not show in the
% outline or table of contents.
\section*{Summary}

\begin{frame}{Summary}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    The \alert{first main message} of your talk in one or two lines.
  \item
    The \alert{second main message} of your talk in one or two lines.
  \item
    Perhaps a \alert{third message}, but not more than that.
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    Outlook
    \begin{itemize}
    \item
      Something you haven't solved.
    \item
      Something else you haven't solved.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}



% All of the following is optional and typically not needed. 
\appendix
\section<presentation>*{\appendixname}
\subsection<presentation>*{For Further Reading}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle<presentation>{For Further Reading}

  \begin{thebibliography}{10}

  \beamertemplatebookbibitems
  % Start with overview books.

  \bibitem{Author1990}
    A.~Author.
    \newblock {\em Handbook of Everything}.
    \newblock Some Press, 1990.


  \beamertemplatearticlebibitems
  % Followed by interesting articles. Keep the list short. 

  \bibitem{Someone2000}
    S.~Someone.
    \newblock On this and that.
    \newblock {\em Journal of This and That}, 2(1):50--100,
    2000.
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does contain the following snippet:

```
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
```

This creates a table of contents (outline) every `\subsection`. If you do not want it, remove it. To just have a toc create a simple frame with `\tableofcontents` and you're done.